# Goodness-of-fit test for multiple components?

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, spectral-analysis, astronomy

I'm running model fits on some simulated data to check my ability to recover my input when I add some noise to it and resample it.

The data is a set of spectra that has a galaxy component and a quasar component added together at varying levels

The free parameters for the fits are a set of 25 coefficients that set the scaling for 25 eigenspectra (18 quasar eigenspectra and 7 galaxy eigenspectra)

I'd like to separately calculate a reduced chi-squared for the fits to the quasar and galaxy and quasar components. When I do this in the standard way,
I get something like what the attached image shows for low signal-to-noise fits.

```py
chi_sq = np.sum( ( (qso_flux_input-qso_flux_output) /qso_std )**2.0 )
nu = float(len(qso_flux_original)) - 25.0
```

(qso_std is calculated by taking the known signal to-noise from the combined spectrum and recalculating the standard deviation at each point for the lone quasar spectrum)

The reported chi squared indicates an extremely overfit spectrum, but a visual inspection shows that this is obviously not the case. [image: Input spectrum vs output spectrum, with residuals in black]

I'm less concerned with how good the fit is in this case (I actually expect it to be bad) and more concerned with why my reduced chi squared is so off of what I expect.

Comment: Some questions: what are the two terms 'input' and 'output' in the equation for the $\chi^2$? Do you mean degrees of freedom in the equation for $\nu$? And what is shown in the plot? There are three curves of flux in dependence of wavelength. What does this mean?

Comment: Input is the model i.e. the noiseless spectrum. Output is the reconstructed spectrum, and is my "data" (this is the input and output from the fit). Yes, I do mean degrees of freedom in the equation for ν. The plot shows the noiseless spectrum (input) in dark blue, the "data" (output) in light blue, and the residual, input - output is in black. The plot represents spectral data: A slit with a prism is placed over a target, and the light from the target is split into its component wavelengths, each of which has a flux measured. It's a histogram of the power in each wavelength bin.